# code not validating for null values

Tags: android, database, validation

I have written the below code to validate the value in the string before saving it to the database.

```
EditText editText2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
           setTime = editText2.getText().toString(); 

           Log.d(setTime, "This is the setTime value");

           if(setTime == null)
           {
               Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Time cannot be NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
           }

           else if(setTime != null)
           {
               cv.put(DatabaseHelper.TIME, setTime);
               db.insert("finalP", DatabaseHelper.TIME, cv);
               db.close();

               editText2.setText("");

               Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Time saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```

But even if "setTime" contains the null value, the "if" part is getting skipped and the control goes into the "else" part directly and saving the null value in database.

Isn't this the correct way to validate??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you string is empty not null. So add check for string length too to if clause.

```
EditText editText2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
setTime = editText2.getText().toString(); 

Log.d(setTime, "This is the setTime value");

if(setTime == null || setTime.length() == 0) {
   Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Time cannot be NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
} else {
   cv.put(DatabaseHelper.TIME, setTime);
   db.insert("finalP", DatabaseHelper.TIME, cv);
   db.close();

   editText2.setText("");

   Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Time saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```